# Precondition error detection using AST

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, static-code-analysis

I am developing a text editor for secure coding. Now I am in the case study stage. I found in the application of AST that Precondition error detection, Auto-completion are possible using AST. Do you have any idea or documents how the following will do with AST.

Comment: This is an enormous topic (parsers, semantic analysis, text editors with integrated parsing and semantic analysis).   One doesn't start a project like this without correspondingly enormous background.  If you had the right background to do such a project, you would not be asking a question this vague.  What have you actually done?  [Yes, I do have an idea].

Comment: @IraBaxter 
My job is design a plugin that will check and correct the code with CERT java coding standard. I am using JetBrains MPS. It will help to work on AST. One example is as follows This is rule developed by CERT [link]https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS01-J.+Normalize+strings+before+validating+them  Here they are saying normalize before validation. So normalization is the root node and validation is the child. So through normalization node only I can go to validation node. I don't know whether this approach is correct or not

Comment: This is a pretty different picture than "I am developing a text editor".  You are using a editing foundation which is stable and integrates AST management.   Now maybe you have a chance to succeed because you can focus on static analysis of the AST.   But we're back to "what do you know" about this topic, and what have you tried.  ...

Comment: ... If I understand the specific CERT example rule, there should be validation code, and there should be normalization code, that are connected by dataflows.  An AST by itself won't give you data flow; where are you going to get it?  The fact that this isn't obvious to you means you don't have the right background for this task.  So go get the education about static analysis first; you're not ready to build a tool like this even with good infrastructure like JetBrains.